# Creating a local dev environment for appsync

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, staging, aws-appsync

We have a react mobile frontend and an AWS appsync backend (DynamoDB, step functions, lambdas, graphql, auth)

Is there an easy way to do this? We have an application and backend in production, and now want to make some changes to our GraphQL components (e.g. schema). Ideally, I would like to have an offline environment which mimics that deployed on AWS.

I found this [Is there a way to test AppSync code locally and/or in CI/CD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51776064/is-there-a-way-to-test-appsync-code-locally-and-or-in-ci-cd), which didn't really have any clear answers. It seems setting up a duplicate environment on AWS (pretty much a staging envirFor lambdas, we have played around with Serverless a little.

We don't use CloudFormation today (maybe we should?), for lambdas, we have played around with Serverless a little, but had issues testing locally with authentication and I think DynamoDB. Ultimately, we just ended up using the AWS console to create components, and then something like Cloud9's IDE to build and debug before deploying to production. I don't like the fragmented dev experience. Lambdas weren't too bad because of Cloud9, but as for GraphQL doesn't seem to have the equivalent.

Eager to learn what the best practices are, and how best (and easy) it is to setup a good dev environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a working Production schema and are looking to simulate a Dev environment, you would have to replicate it manually for now.

We recently [launched](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/announcing-aws-amplify-console/) [Amplify Console](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/console/), to specifically address the best practices around CI/CD, and manage your API across stages. A recommended practice would be to use [Amplify CLI](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/concept) which internally uses CloudFormation nested stacks to simplify the process of creating and maintaining your AWS AppSync APIs. In addition to this, Amplify CLI also gives you out of the box scaffolding for your Request/Response Mapping Templates in CloudFormation with just a simple annotated schema.

You could use some of these tools as a recommended practice for maintaining cloud resources. We are also actively working towards enhancing the Developer Experience for some of these workflows.

Comment: Has there been any progress on this lately? Like have you guys been able to develop amplify such that it can used to write just the server when my consumer is just the backend?